# Always show map marker title in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm adding default Marker to GoogleMap the following way:

```
GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.editMapMap)).getMap();

MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
markerOptions.position(currentLocation.getCoordinate());
markerOptions.title(Utils.getLocationString(currentLocation.getCoordinate()));
markerOptions.snippet("Blah");

locationMarker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
locationMarker.setDraggable(true);
```

How can I make marker always show title and snippet without touch? I also would like to disable hiding them on touch.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

It is very easy:

```
locationMarker.showInfoWindow();
```

Answer (score 7):

use `showInfoWindow()` and add marker as below.

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentPosition).title("Your text"));
marker.showInfoWindow();
```

Comment: Looks as if several markers can't showInfo at the same time without clicking on them?

Comment: Thansk, that´s not in Microsoft's Documentation

Answer (score 5):

Just return false for `onMarkerClickListener`, if you return true shows the `infoWindow`.

To hide title when we click on marker:

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
...

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {     
  Log.i(TAG,"marker arg0 = "+arg0);               
  return false;
}
```

If we return true title will be display, else if we return false title won't display.

Comment: is this possible for google maps v2? i am returning false but the marker still displays the title...

Comment: yes. It works for V2. I tried for v2 only. Another alternative is there, that is put title as empty string. i.e "". But is not good

Answer (score 5):

There are two methods for showing and hiding the markers. The boolean return value simply prevents the default behaviour from taking place (false) or allows it to happen (true). In other words, it informs the system whether you consumed the event or not. See [Google API Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener.html).

```
private GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener onMarkerClickedListener = new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        if (marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
            marker.hideInfoWindow();
        } else {
            marker.showInfoWindow();
        }
        return true;
    }
};

mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(onMarkerClickedListener);
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old but I'll post my answer here in case it helps someone.

Info windows would not work for my case and I wanted the titles to show only if there is room, potentially hiding if not enough room to display so that they don't overlap each other.

I found no solution on the internet so I rolled up my sleeves and made this library which solves my problem, hopefully it will help others too:

https://github.com/androidseb/android-google-maps-floating-marker-titles

Here is a preview of how it works:

[image: preview]

Answer (score 1):

Hold but here is my answer:

From the documentation, there is an text saying that info window is shown one at time, so there is no way to do that:

> "An info window allows you to display information to the user when they
>   tap on a marker. ***Only one info window is displayed at a time***. If a
>   user clicks on a marker, the current info window will be closed and
>   the new info window will be displayed. Note that if the user clicks on
>   a marker that is currently showing an info window, that info window
>   closes and re-opens."

Maps api doc says:

> "Best practices: For the best user experience, only one info window should be open on the map at any one time. Multiple info windows make the map appear cluttered. If you only need one info window at a time, you can create just one `InfoWindow` object and open it at different locations or markers upon map events, such as user clicks. If you do need more than one info window, you can display multiple `InfoWindow` objects at the same time."

on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows