# How to get actual Google Maps icon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm wondering if it is possible to reproduce the icons used in Google Maps.  I'm currently using the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/) to add a search feature to my website.  Each result has an icon field, however those icons are different from what Google Maps is using.  Is it possible to somehow get the icons they are using?

The actual icon on Google maps (for hospitals) looks like:

[image]

However, the icon given to me for a hospital result looks like:

[image]

Comment: I can't understand what you achieve from this but may this link help to as you want  : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

Comment: also share code snippet so get your point very well what to achieve

Comment: Take a look at the 3 kinds of icons in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306724/how-to-show-both-markericon-and-tittle-in-google-map-as-like-google-apps/39408057#39408057